# Why is there a different collisions point with constant setup?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have a bouncing ball in my game. Every time I start the game, the ball direction (a Vector3) and speed are constant. The ball has a rigidbody too. I'm using `OnTriggerEnter` to detect collisions.

After starting the game the ball will move to a wall. The question is, why is the collision point different every time?

Comment: what do you mean by collision point is different? can you give a screenshot image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used `FixedUpdate()` insted of `FixUpdate()` and problem solved.